# Redis Cluster Gives Error in Magento-2

Tags: magento2, cache, redis, cm-redissession

I have implemented Redis cluster in my local machine with three masters and three slaves. I did all the required configuration in my app/etc/env.php file and when I am accessing the project url, it shows fatal error as follows.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CredisException' with message 'MOVED 12307 127.0.0.1:7002' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Credis/Client.php:1022 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/lib/internal/Credis/Client.php(788):
```

Any idea how to fix this ?I have checked the similar questions posted here, but unfortunately couldn't find any solution.